# What options are available for the rasterio .update() method?

Tags: python, geotiff-tiff, clip, fiona, rasterio

I have a script which clips raster data by a shapefile using rasterio and fiona:

```
import fiona
import rasterio
import rasterio.mask

def clip_raster(shp, imagery, out_imagery):
    with fiona.open(shp, "r") as shapefile:
        features = [feature["geometry"] for feature in shapefile]

    with rasterio.open(imagery) as src:
        out_image, out_transform = rasterio.mask.mask(src, features, crop=True)
        out_meta = src.meta.copy()

    out_meta.update({"driver": "GTiff",
                     "height": out_image.shape[1],
                     "width": out_image.shape[2],
                     "transform": out_transform,
                     "compress": "LZW",
                     "nodata": 255})
    with rasterio.open(out_imagery, "w", **out_meta) as dest:
        dest.write(out_image)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    shp = r'/path/to/shapefile.shp'
    imagery = r'/path/to/input_imagery.tif'
    out_imagery = r'/path/to/output_imagery.tif'

    clip_raster(shp, imagery, out_imagery)
```

You can see that the `.update()` method has a variety of options such as setting the compression type (`"compress": "LZW"`) or nodata value (`"nodata": 255`):

```
out_meta.update({"driver": "GTiff",
                 "height": out_image.shape[1],
                 "width": out_image.shape[2],
                 "transform": out_transform,
                 "compress": "LZW",
                 "nodata": 255})
```

Is there a list or documentation of all the available options available to the `.update()` method when writing raster data using rasterio?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`rasterio` objects don't have an update method. Your `out_meta` var is a python [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), which is being [updated](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=update#dict.update) and is then passed to the `rasterio.open` method as keyword args using `**` [dict unpacking](http://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/dict_unpack.html).

The main keyword arguments for the `rasterio.open` method are documented in ["Opening a dataset in writing mode"](http://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#opening-a-dataset-in-writing-mode):

> - `driver`: the name of the desired format driver
> - `width`: the number of columns of the dataset
> - `height`: the number of rows of the dataset
> - `count`: a count of the dataset bands dtype: the data type of the dataset
> - `crs`: a coordinate reference system identifier or description
> - `transform`: an affine transformation matrix, and
> - `nodata`: a “nodata” value

You should also read the docs for [creation options](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/image_options.html) which notes:

> Each format has it’s own set of driver-specific creation options that can be used to fine tune the output rasters. For details on a particular driver, see the [formats list](http://gdal.org/formats_list.html).
>
> For the purposes of this document, we will focus on the GeoTIFF creation options. Some of the common [GeoTIFF creation options](http://gdal.org/frmt_gtiff.html) include:
>
> - `TILED`, `BLOCKXSIZE`, and `BLOCKYSIZE` to define the internal tiling
> - `COMPRESS` to define the compression method
> - `PHOTOMETRIC` to define the band’s color interpretation

Answer (score 1):

If you look in the rasterio `__init__.py` file, you'll see the following parameters listed for the open and update method:

```
Parameters
----------
mode: string
    "r" (read), "r+" (read/write), or "w" (write)
driver: string
    driver code specifying the format name (e.g. "GTiff" or
    "JPEG"). See GDAL docs at
    http://www.gdal.org/formats_list.html (optional, required
    for writing).
width: int
    number of pixels per line
    (optional, required for write)
height: int
    number of lines
    (optional, required for write)
count: int > 0
    number of bands
    (optional, required for write)
dtype: rasterio.dtype
    the data type for bands such as ``rasterio.ubyte`` for
    8-bit bands or ``rasterio.uint16`` for 16-bit bands
    (optional, required for write)
crs: dict or string
    Coordinate reference system
    (optional, recommended for write)
transform: Affine instance
    Affine transformation mapping the pixel space to geographic
    space (optional, recommended for writing).
nodata: number
    Defines pixel value to be interpreted as null/nodata
    (optional, recommended for write)
```

which is funny because I don't see "compress" listed. I am using an older version of rasterio though. (0.36 I believe)

Comment: You don't see "compress" listed as it's a format [creation option](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/image_options.html#creation-options).  It's captured by the optional extra keyword arguments [`**kwargs`](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio/blob/master/rasterio/__init__.py#L61).